# How do I determine when scroll UIDatePicker completed?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I use `UIDatePicker` and I want to know when scrolling in `UIDatePicker` is over. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UIDatePicker does not expose the scrolling events, but does send an event when the selected value has changed. You can use UIControlEventValueChanged to track this.

```
[myDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```